# How to use the equation of the circle in the driver expression?

Tags: animation, drivers, mathematics

How to use the equation of the circle in the driver expression?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

x^2 + y^2 = 1 we can write in driver expression as **sqrt(1-scale^2)**

[image]